# How do you use $('document').ready(function()) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onload

I have a piece of code that is working fine in IE, but it doesn’t run in Firefox. I think the problem is that I have not been able to implement `$('document').ready(function)`. The structure of my json is like [{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}].
I will be very thankful if someone can see my code & help me in correctly implementing it. Here is my code:

```
<html><head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2
     /jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 
     $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
     $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
     document.form1.fruits.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
     });});
     });
     </script></head>
     <body><form name="form1">
     My favourite fruit is :
     <select name="fruits" id="fruits" /></form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: OH OK, thanX for pointing, actually I did not know that I have to accept also for recognition .....

Comment: Its not something silly like the way you are setting fruits' options with document.form1.fruits.options[i] is it? Just wondering if this is what firefox is disliking rather than the ajax/onload parts. If you stick in an alert just before that does it get triggered? Its a good way of testing. Or install firebug and look at the javascript console for errors.

Comment: firebug is always saying 'syntax error' and " 'a' undefined ......" many times.For syntax error, its pointing on closing braces & parenthesis. I checked many times but I did not find any misplaced OR missed brace/parenthesis. U can see it too.One more thing is if its syntax error, than why its running in ie.

Comment: no, alert doesn't trigger any option, even not index i.e. i. The Firebug console is showing no error, just 4 warnings.

Comment: I have corrected the code, it was localhost addressing method problem. I edited the code, 127.0.0.1 should be used in spite of localhost in geJson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run  `$(document).ready(function() {doStuff})`. This will automatically run when the document is ready.

It's best practice, at least in my opinion, that you don't put any events in the html itself. This way you separate the structure of an html document from it's behavior. Instead attach events in the $(document).ready function.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() { 
           $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
             var selectElem = $('#fruits');

             for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
               selectElem.append($('<option>').html(jsonData[i].options));
             }

           });
       });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form1">
      My favourite fruit is :
      <select name="fruits" id="fruits" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
I tested with the following and mocked the json object since I can't make that call myself.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           var jsonData = JSON.parse('[{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}]');
           var selectElem = $('#fruits');

           for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) { 
             selectElem.append($('<option>').html(jsonData[i].options));
           }

       });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form1">
      My favourite fruit is :
      <select name="fruits" id="fruits" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: now there is one confusion. From these answers it is now seeming 2 me that there is only $(document).ready(function() has to be used as top level function in script, inside which is $.getJson used. While my understanding is that I its top level function & inside it I have to define another function(like I define preLoad()) that will implement $.getJson & this function will be called like I called it with onLoad event. Can u kindly answer me about it.

Comment: I refer you to http://api.jquery.com/ready/. The .ready function will get called once the page has fully loaded. You can define the function multiple times if you'd like, they will get run lexically as it appeared on the page. I was merely saying that you should avoid using the onLoad event in the html itself as it doesn't provide for much flexibility in design.

Comment: OK, thanks that have had a clear example. I have edited the code now but its behaving same i.e. executing in IE but not in firefox. Whats trouble now.

Comment: Can you post your console output or give more indication as to /how/ its now working?

Comment: I just tested that exact and it worked in both chrome and firefox. The only difference is that instead of getting the json, I mocked it with just `var jsonData = JSON.parse('[{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}]');` as you said this is how your data came out. That said, I think the problem is with your json service not returning the right thing.

Comment: with current code, console is showing no error & 4 warnings. with ur code, it says '$ not defined' highlighting this line:  $(document).ready(function().  
 it seems funny. I check it by alert but alert did not trigger anything even i i.e. index

Comment: actually this json data I am copying by running php file that echoes the json data. As u can see, it is converted into jason format exactly, something happen in getJson. I even tried to change jquery library source, & also using full jquery .each syntax it may be do something good but.  [{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}]

Comment: `$ not defined` means jQuery isn't getting imported. I had the problem at first because the code you posted split the jQuery import in two, which put a space in the path, so it couldn't find it.

Comment: I am taking care of space as if I add an artificial space, than ie also stops working.

Comment: Does the second set of code work? copy the whole thing as is into a file and run it. Because I can definitely confirm that that works. So I can probably guarantee it's your ajax service that is failing.

Comment: I change the jquery reference to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" & now it raises this error Error poiting jquery library:                                       this.ratedStars is undefined
Source File: http://old.nabble.com/jQuery,-$-is-Not-Defined-Errors-td18801392s27240.html
Line: 194                                                          Error: t is null
Source File: http://old.nabble.com/jQuery,-$-is-Not-Defined-Errors-td18801392s27240.html
Line: 1411

Comment: OK, with ur 2nd set of code, its now other way round. i.e. its working in FF but not IE.

Comment: I'm on a linux box right now, so I can't test IE. I'll test it at home a little later and will keep checking this thread.

Comment: I have fixed the prohttp://stackoverflow.com/users/474780/shoebox639blem. It was the localhost addressing problem. In spite of using $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData){}, it should be $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1(/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {}, then has no problem either in ie or ff. thanX a Lot shoebox639  all other guys for all the help. ur 1st code is also working now with cottection made by me in both ie & ff.

Answer (score 4):

Short version (suggested by meeger): don't use single quotes around document.

`document` is a variable that comes with JavaScript (at least in the browser context). Instead, try the following for the relevant line.

`$(document).ready(function() {`

You'll also want to take the onLoad attribute off of the body tag, else it will run twice.

Comment: To summarize, don't use single quotes around `document`.

Comment: @some Use of double quotes wasn't in question; you could also have said "don't use brackets or dollar signs or periods or commas around `document`"

Answer (score 2):

Here it is in all its glory.  The shorthand, awesome version:

**UPDATED**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
            var cacheFruits = $('#fruits'),
                cacheOption = $(document.createElement('option'));

            $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
                cacheFruits.append(
                    cacheOption.clone().attr('value', j.options).html(j.options)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Of course, I don't know what your JSON structure is, so you may need to play around with the append section of the code.

There should be no reason why the above would not work.

Comment: I prefer to use `$.ready(function)` as it is slightly less magically named. [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Just out of curiosity, why not `$('<option/>')` for the creation?

Comment: I respect your position, but I wouldn't call this one magic.  Well, actually I would, but for different reasons.  ;)  The reason for the `document.createElement()` is becuase it's faster than the string-parsed `$('<option/>')` version.

Comment: @Stephen no, it is not working. U say I need to drop <body onload> mean it should only be a normal body tag <BODY>. The structure of my json is like [{"options":"smart_exp"},{"options":"user_intf"},{"options":"blahblah"}].

Comment: I edited the code, its still running in ie but not in firefox. Can u see now whats problem. thanX

Comment: I updated the code.  If it doesn't work, then you've got other problems.  Possibly a duplicate ID or other invalid HTML issues.

Comment: I tested ur code with now I find correction & its working in both ie & ff with correction I made. thanX a lot 4 the help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need quotes around document.  Once the page has completely loaded, it will start executing whatever you have defined in ready()

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(this).getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
    $(this).each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
      document.form1.fruits.options[i] = new Option(j.options);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your json data should be in this format:

```
[{'text':'sometext','value':'somevalue'},{'text':'sometext','value':'somevalue'}];


$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(this).getJSON("http://localhost/conn_mysql.php", function (jsonData) {
    var options = [];
    $.each(jsonData, function (i, j) {
      options.push('<option value="' + j.value + '">'  + j.text + '</option>');
    });
    $('#fruits').html( options.join(''));
  });
});
```

Please note that there may be an encoding/escaping issues here. 
Make sure that you escape the text properly from the server side.
htmlentities, htmlspecialchars can help you with that.

This should work in most browsers

Comment: I have tested it, it even don't run in ie with now corrected code.